Azure Data Share resource behavior during Subscription migration to different tenant
Let's say I create an Azure Data Share (ADS) resource called ads1 in the Azure subscription S1 in the AAD tenant T1. Now, in the ADS resource ads1 I create an In-Place share called share1. In share1 I add a dataset called d1 that points to a Kusto database (sharing the whole database) called DB1 which is part of the Kusto cluster K1. The Kusto cluster is also part of the Azure subscription S1 in the AAD tenant T1. Now for share1 I add certain recipient Joe from another team. So this way invitation for share1 is sent to Joe. Now Joe receives this invitation on his end and accepts the invitation into the Azure Data Share resource called ads2 which is part of his team's Azure subscription S2 , which is also in the same AAD tenant T1 itself. After accepting the received share into ads2 , Joe needs to map the dataset d1 to some target cluster. So he maps the dataset d1 to the Kusto cluster K2 which exists as part of S2 subscription in T1 tenant itself. This way now Joe can access the source database DB1 data through the cluster K2. Now let's say I suddenly move my whole subscription S1 to another AAD tenant called T2. There is no change of region anywhere , only the whole subscription is moving from T1 to T2 , so obviously all the resources under S1 will also move from tenant T1 to tenant T2. So I have the following questions:-

Will the Share-Subscription relation (here I am referring to
'Subscription' in Azure Data Share context)  between ads1 and ads2
be broken because of this move?
Will this move maintain the data access for Joe seamlessly or a totally new share request will need to be sent to Joe after the move of S1 to T1 completes?

